# Truncate all digits except first

Tags: javascript, math, truncate

I have a function that returns: `3333333333333333/5000000000000000` which is meaningless. How do I truncate all digits except the first, so it becomes `3/5` ?

Comment: The two fractions aren't equal. Why don't you reduce the fraction instead (which won't work for your example, as it's irreducible)?

Comment: Its not about fraction, I'm calculating device aspect ratio to 3/5 is perfect :)

Comment: are you missing a decimal? because otherwise `3333333333333333/5000000000000000` is no where near perfect XD

Comment: @Nimbuz: Can you post that function? This seems like a hack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var frac = '3333333333333333/5000000000000000';
var parts = frac.split('/');
var simpler = parts[0][0]+'/'+parts[1][0];
```

Answer (score 4):

I can't get why do you need this, but anyway

```
var x = 3333333333333333;
var y = 5000000000000000;
var result = (Number)(String(x).charAt(0)) / (Number)(String(y).charAt(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this method too...

```
var x = 3333333333333333;
var y = 5000000000000000;
var result = (Number)(String(x).substring(0,1)) / (Number)(String(y).subsring(0,1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach..

```
function truncate(v) {
    return v.substring(v.indexOf('/') - 1, v.indexOf('/') + 2);
}
```